# lodash debounce render does not work, accumulates and then is called many times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, debouncing

Now the renderer works in this way, with each input of a value, it waits one second and then it is called, and it turns out that it can be called many times in a row. What needs to be done is that when the user has finished typing, the Testrender function is called only once, now it is called many times during typing

I do not understand why, when passing data between components, the function works without delay and does not maintain its purpose

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-meadow-o7bbqd?file=/src/components/Testrender/index.tsx:135-145

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import Testrender from "./Testrender";

const Main_page = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <Input count={count} setCount={setCount} />
      <Testrender count={count} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Main_page;
```

--

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  count: string;
  setCount: (searchString: string) => void;
}

const Input = ({ count, setCount }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="test-input"
        value={count}
        onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="test render"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

--

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

interface Props {
  count: string;
}

const Testrender = ({ count }: Props) => {
  const request = debounce((stateValue: any) => {
    console.log("render");
  }, 1000);

  const changes = useCallback(request, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    changes(count);
  }, [count]);

  return <div>index</div>;
};

export default Testrender;
```

Comment: It would be better to debounce the input updates to state than to try and debounce the rendering of a component. In other words, it's all the intermediate enqueued state updates that cause `Testrender` to rerender, so it ***don't*** enqueue the intermediate values you don't care about. The answer below isn't preventing the rerenders, it is only debouncing the callback to console log `"render"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each render of a `Testrender` component create a new `request` function, each time useEffect of `Testrender` is triggered, it is actually calling a different `request` function.

In case you do multiple update to count, you will call a different debounced function each time, they will add up in parallel and you will eventually have multiple console.log instead of delaying the same debounced function.

You can use useState to init a debounced function and ensure it will not be created again

```
const Testrender = ({ count }: Props) => {
  const [changes] = useState(() => {
    return debounce((value) => {
      console.log("render")
    }, 1000);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    changes(count);
  }, [count]);

  return <div>index</div>;
};
```

Comment: does not work will be called immediately

Comment: Sorry forgot the delay param to debouce call, edited !

Comment: why is it empty? }, []); substituted your rendering option is also called immediately

Comment: The empty array is also an error, edited ! (wrong copy/paste, useState does not take a dependency array)

Comment: can this problem be solved in another way or perhaps only in this way?

Comment: Well any way that help you keep value that does not change between render would solve this issue. useState is probably the most simple and straightforward one but you can also use useMemo and probably useRef

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it using useMemo?

Comment: That would looks like `const change = useMemo(() => debounce(value => { console.log('render') }), [])`